# C main function variations

Tags: c

Is there a difference or pros and cons betweeen those variations?

1. `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return 1; }`
2. `int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { return 1; }`

Comment: They are both equivalent.  I also recommend [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: @yasin: one takes one more keystroke.

Comment: I know that it is equivalent , so it does the same but are there any pros and cons while using both?

Comment: One is one more character to type